# Date time string insert to db

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hi I am trying to insert the following to SQL Server 2005:

```
INSERT INTO tb_UserLoginTimes (UserID, LoginDateTime)
VALUES (1235,2010/07/06 10:38:44)
```

But am getting the following error.

```
Incorrect syntax near '10'.
```

Do I need to escape the colon?

If so how do I do that?

Real noob at this so my apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you simply need to enclose your date in quotes:

```
... VALUES (1235, '2010/07/06 10:38:44')
```

[Try it out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6172/date-time-string-insert-to-db) in the [SEDE](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/). If you leave out the quotes, you'll get the same syntax error you're reporting.

Comment: Bingo - apparently I have to wait to accept the answer. - Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 2010/07/06 10:38:44 use the ANSI SQL Standard (YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS)

```
'20100706 10:38:44'
```

Comment: ANSI? Although the one you've used is one of only two SQL Server 2005 DATETIME representations that is considered unambiguous as regards language settings, it is other *other* one that most closely resembles the ANSI Standard i.e. `'2010-07-06T10:38:44'`. The actual ANSI Standard omits the `T`.